# Like count on my website posts differs from like count in facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

I have a Wordpress-based blog with like button integration.

After creating a new post on the blog I always share it on my FB profile and get some likes and comments there (see 24 total likes in this [image](http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-Like-error-1.png)) but those won't show in the blog post (in this [image](http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-Like-error-2.png) you can see only 5 total likes for the same post; both screenshots were taken simultaneously).

I'm having this problem 2 or 3 weeks ago, the like count was working fine previously.

This other post (http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-Like-error-3.png) is showing zero likes in my blog, but I know for sure it had +100 likes before all this began. In my FB profile, this same post shows 7 likes, 2 shares, and a comment (http://www.manuelmedina.com.mx/images/FB-Like-error-4.png). Many friends copy-pasted the link  on their own profiles, letting it grow to up to 100 total likes, which were visible in the post page on my blog, but now it's back to zero and that makes me crazy.

I'm not sure of this but I think the like count shown in my blog is counting only like button clicks, and not considering likes made in FB profiles.

I'm sure you'll had figured this out but I'm a novice in FB development, so I need some serious help.

Comment: Sorry for posting a bad question, if someone can tell me how to improve it, i'm willing to know.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure of this but I think the like count shown in my blog is
>   counting only like button clicks, and not considering likes made in FB
>   profiles.

You answered your question in the quesiton itself already! The like count from the like button only shows how many people clicked on it. You can't change that. 
If you necessarily want to show the like count of your facebook post, get its permalink by clicking on its date (e.g. "15 days ago"). Then get the information from the Graph API by going to `http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.permalink-in-here.com/blabla`, decode the JSON (see phps [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for example) so you can read the post-count, then you can echo it out on your page. 
If you want to be clever you could use the like button without a count and add the number just behind it in the same style as facebook does (that's against FB's Terms and Conditions though!!!!). Be aware that this will *only* count the post-likes, not the *real* ones from clicks on the actual like-button!

To improve your question: Ask a question and make sure to post some relevant code in the future!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the real problem is that I'm sure the like count was (about 3 weeks ago) counting all likes-shares-comments made in FB (that's how it's supposed to work right?) and not only the like button clicks within the blog, but now all those likes are missing. By now I believe that when I created my App_ID (which i didn't have previously) somehow my URL was "marked" and now i need to rewrite the plugin code using the App_ID, so the count can take all the likes-shares-comments. Do you think that would do?

Comment: I'm very glad you took the time to answer, I'm very new in development.